# A limit like a Riemann sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R_+$ be a non-negative continuous function.

For all integer $n \geq 1$, we define :

$$U_n=\left(\frac 1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \sqrt[n]{f\left(\frac kn\right)}\right)^n$$

What can be said about : $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} U_n ?$$

**What I have done till now:**

Using concavity of $x \mapsto \sqrt[n]{x}$
 I proved that $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} U_n \leq  \int_0^1 f(t) dt $$

Comment: looks like $\exp\int_0^1\log f(x)\,dx$

Comment: $\log f(x)$  has not  sense because we dont have $f(x) > 0$, we have only $f(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: @unopetit, then please change the "positive" to "non-negative"! Positive, - at least for many people - implies non-zero.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Thank you for editing!(Merci beaucoup!)

Comment: in this "French-positive" case I would still guess that we just set $\log 0=-\infty$ and $\exp (-\infty) =0$

Comment: Simply define $\ln 0 =-\infty.$

Comment: Dans le cas où $f>0$ et $\lim_{0^+} f >0$, il est facile de montrer que ça converge vers $\exp(\int_0^1 \ln f(t) dt)$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Parlez Anglais, si vous plait, alors nous comprenons tous.  Oui?

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't think that link is too useful here, since we don''t have $(\int_0^1f^{1/n})^n,$ but rather $(\int_0^1R_n(f^{1/n}))^n,$ where $R_n(g)$ denotes the standard Riemann sum operator.

Comment: @zhw you are very right. I cancel this link.

Comment: @JeanMarie OK, but I think the link was still a good comment, because that is the result people who know it would go to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we sketch a way forward.  First, we assume that $f$ is strictly positive.

Then, we can write

$$\sqrt[n]{f(k/n)}=e^{\frac1n \log(f(k/n))}=1+\frac{\log(f(k/n))}{n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right) \tag1$$

Using $(1)$ it is easy to see that

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[n]{f(k/n)}\right)^n&=\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{\log(f(k/n))}{n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\right)^n\\\\
&=\left(1+\frac{\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n\log(f(k/n))}{n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)^n
\end{align}$$

whereupon taking the limit yields

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[n]{f(k/n)}\right)^n=e^{\int_0^1\log(f(x))\,dx}$$

Comment: The note at the end seems wrong

Comment: @user8268 I think you're right. For example if $f=0$ on $[0,1/2],$ then the limit is $0.$

Comment: @zhw I should have qualified my late night thinking.  If the set $I$ is of measure $0$, then for $x\in I$, $f(x)=0$, the result still holds.  If the set $I$ has positive measure with $f=0$ on $I$, then the result is $0$.  Does that sound correct now?

Comment: I think the result is always true when we set $\log0=-\infty$ and $\exp(-\infty)=0$.

Comment: Not If the set has measure $0$.

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Comment: Dr., that is a really nice answer for $f$ positive and continuous, +1. I don't know why anyone down voted it, but as we know, the up and down votes at MSE can be as weird as human behavior itself. I'll get to your question in a bit.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you!  Much appreciative.  I believe the result holds if $f>0$ almost always.

Comment: But in that case couldn't $\int_0^1 \ln f = -\infty?$

Comment: Well, suppose $f(x)=x$.  Surely $\int_0^1 \log(x)\,dx$ converges.

Comment: Sure but that's just one example. What if $f(x) = e^{-1/x}?$

Comment: So, we need additional restrictions on $f$.

Comment: Will think about it, coffee is on the stove.

Comment: Sounds good.  Enjoy.

Comment: @zhw. If $\int_0^1 \log(f(x))\,dx$ exists as an improper Riemann integral, then that should suffice.

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm not sure why we want to exclude $\int_0^1 \ln f = -\infty.$ I'm pretty sure that for $f(x)= e^{-1/x}$ the result holds if we use the  convention $e^{-\infty}=0.$

Comment: @zhw. I see your point.

Comment: @Dr.MV I found a counterexample! See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

@Dr.MV has sketched a nice proof that

$$\tag 1 U_n(f) \to \exp (\int_0^1 \ln f(x)\, dx)$$

if $f$ is positive and continuous on $[0,1].$ But what if positivity is relaxed to nonnegavity, as in the statement of the problem? In that case we could have $\int_0^1 \ln f = -\infty.$ But $(1)$ might still be true if we use the natural convention $e^{-\infty} = 0.$ For example if $f=0$ on any subinterval, then $(1)$ still holds. It also holds for $f(x) = e^{-1/x}.$

Interestingly, $(1)$ can fail for $f$ nonnegative, even if $\int_0^1 \ln f$ converges. To get the gist of the idea, let's first find a Riemann integrable, though not continuous, function for which the result fails. Choose a sequence of positive integers $1<m_1 < m_2 < \cdots,$ with $m_{k+1} > m_k^2$ for all $k.$ For each $k=1,2,\dots ,$ consider the finite sets

$$F_k = \{1/m_k^2, 2/m_k^2,3/m_k^2, \dots ,m_k/m_k^2 = 1/m_k\}.$$

The $F_k$ are pairwise disjoint, and every point in $F_{k+1}$ lies to the left of every point in $F_k.$

Define

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& x\in \cup_{k=1}^\infty F_k\\x, & x\in [0,1]\setminus \cup_{k=1}^\infty F_k\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1],$ and $\int_0^1\ln f(x)\,dx = \int_0^1\ln x\,dx = -1.$ But note that for each $k,$

$$\frac{1}{m_k^2} \sum_{j=1}^{m_k^2}f(j/m_k^2)^{1/m_k^2} = \frac{1}{m_k^2}\sum_{j=m_k+1}^{m_k^2}f(j/m_k^2)^{1/m_k^2} \le \frac{1}{m_k^2}\sum_{j=m_k+1}^{m_k^2}1$$ $$ = \frac{1}{m_k^2}(m_k^2-m_k) = 1- 1/m_k.$$

Thus as $k\to \infty,$ $U_{m_k^2} \le (1- 1/m_k)^{m_k^2} \to 0.$ Therefore $(1)$ fails for this $f$ as claimed.

How do we show there is a continuous counterexample? We model it on the the above. At this point I'll be descriptive rather than precise. From each point $ a\in\cup_{k=1}^\infty F_k,$ we consider two nearly vertical rays from $(a,0)$ of positive and negative slope. These rays will intersect $y=x$ in points $(b,b),(c,c),$ where $b<a<c.$ We can make $c-b$ as small as we like. The definition of $f$ on $[b,c]$ is then the piecwise linear function connecting $(b,b),(a.0),(c,c).$ If we do this methodically for every point in $\cup_{k=1}^\infty F_k,$ making each "$[b,c]$ interval" very small, and if we define $f(x)=x$ everywhere else, we'll have a continuous counterexample.

Comment: There must be a typographical error.  How do we have the estimate $$\frac{1}{m_k^2} \sum_{k=1}^{m_k^2}f(k/m_k^2)^{1/m_k^2} \le \frac{1}{m_k^2}\sum_{k=m_k+1}^{m_k^2}f(k/m_k^2)^{1/m_k^2}\,\,?$$

Comment: @Dr.MV Ah you're right, the index of summation should be $j$ or something. Thanks. Edited.

Comment: Well yes, but the term on the right-hand side must be less than or equal to the one on the left-hand side since the terms of the sum are non-negative and $m_k+1>1$, is it not?

Comment: Well they're equal actually, because $f(j/m_k^2)^{m_k^2} = 0, j = 1, \dots, m_k.$ But good point, I'll put in the equal sign. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: That sounds correct.  And you're more than welcome my friend!